# Is there a better way to do the following (having a component return null)?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Is there a better way to do the following (having a component return null)?

In my `Page` component I need to update my `pageTitle` state that is rendered in a component further up the tree.

layout.tsx:

```
import { PageTitleProvider } from "@/contexts/page-title-context";    
import Breadcrumbs from "../ui/breadcrumbs";
import PageTitle from "@/app/ui/page-title";


export default function Layout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div className="lg:pl-72">
          <main>
            <PageTitleProvider>
              <div className="bg-white px-4 pt-10 lg:px-8">
                    <Breadcrumbs />
                    <h1>
                      <PageTitle />
                    </h1>
              </div>
              <div>{children}</div>
            </PageTitleProvider>
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

page.tsx:

```
import SetPageTitle from "@/app/ui/set-page-title";

export default async function Page() {
  return (
    <>
      <SetPageTitle pageTitle={"Overview"} />
      <div>More stuff here...</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

set-page-title.tsx:

```
"use client";

import usePageTitle from "@/contexts/page-title-context";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function SetPageTitle({ pageTitle }: { pageTitle: string }) {
  const { setPageTitle } = usePageTitle();
  useEffect(() => {
    setPageTitle(pageTitle);
  }, [pageTitle, setPageTitle]);

  return null;
}
```

Can I get rid of `return null`?

Comment: "a better way" is very ambiguous and broadly open to interpretation.  What issue are you facing with the current approach you have?  Is there a particular aspect of your above code that you are hoping to address (speed?  user experience? code cleanliness/consistency? ...... ??)

Comment: Better as in why do I need to create a component that returns nothing when all I want to do is call setPageTitle from my child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, this is how I solved it:

pages-metadata.ts:

```
interface Page {
  title: string;
  path: string;
}

const pages: Page[] = [
  { title: "Page 1", path: "/page-1" },
  { title: "Page 2", path: "/page-2" },
  
];

export default pages;
```

page-title.tsx:

```
"use client";

import pages from "@/data/pages-metadata";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

const getPageTitle = (pathname: string) => {
  const page = pages.find((p) => p.path === pathname);
  return page ? page.title : "Page Not Found";
};

export default function PageTitle() {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const pageTitle = getPageTitle(pathname);

  return <>{pageTitle}</>;
}
```

layout.tsx:

```
export default function Layout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
return (
    <>
      <div>
                      <PageTitle />
</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: This only works because the page titles are static. As soon as you want it to depend on something from `<Page>` you'll need to go back to your previous scheme

Comment: You're right. But my page hierarchy is static so this solution will do.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just call `setPageTitle()` in `<Page>`?

Your code for `SetPageTitle` isn't really a Component (since it isn't really returning JSX).

You could make SetPageTitle into a hook that you could then use from within `<Page>`:

```js
"use client";

import usePageTitle from "@/contexts/page-title-context";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function useSetPageTitle({ pageTitle }: { pageTitle: string }) {
  const { setPageTitle } = usePageTitle();
  useEffect(() => {
    setPageTitle(pageTitle);
  }, [pageTitle, setPageTitle]);
}
```

and then use `useSetPageTitle()` in `<Page>` but I don't see any real benefit over simply using `setPageTitle()` directly in `<Page>`

Comment: Will I not have to annotate my Page component as "use client" then?